# Как сделать фиксирующие подчеркивание?

Tags: javascript, css

Всем привет! Такая проблема, что не могу зафиксировать нижнее подчеркивание. На css сделал нижнее подчеркивание с помощью before. Все работает. Но мне нужно, чтоб при клике на этот элемент списка, подчеркивание фиксировалось.

```css
.m-cat ul{
    padding: 0;
}
.m-cat li{
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.m-cat li::before{
    content: "";
    height: 1.5px;
    background: #999;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    transition: .2s ease;
}
.m-cat li:hover::before{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<aside class="m-cat">
    <nav>
        <ul id="m-cat-ul">
            <li data-url="/">Все товары</li>
            <li>Электроника</li>
            <li>Дом</li>
            <li>Автотовары</li>
            <li>Спорт и развлечения</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</aside>
```

Я попробовал добавить класс с помощью js, к элементу списка, но выглядит не очень. Как уже при клике удалить прежние свойства? Код:

```js
    let list = document.getElementById('m-cat-ul');
    list.addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
     let item = event.target;
     item.classList.add('m-cat-li__active');
    })
```

```css
    .m-cat ul{
     padding: 0;
    }
    .m-cat li{
     padding: 10px 0;
     position: relative;
     cursor: pointer;
    }
    .m-cat li::before{
     content: "";
     height: 1.5px;
     background: #999;
     width: 0;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     left:0;
     transition: .2s ease;
    }
    .m-cat li:hover::before{
     width: 100%;
    }
    .m-cat-li__active{
     border-bottom: 1.5px solid #999;
    }
```

```html
<aside class="m-cat">
  <nav>
    <ul id="m-cat-ul">
     <li data-url="/">Все товары</li>
     <li>Электроника</li>
     <li>Дом</li>
     <li>Автотовары</li>
     <li>Спорт и развлечения</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</aside>
```

Comment: а tabindex  Вас устроит?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Хм.. а без него получится?)

Comment: Либо js либо он

Comment: Выбираю js))))))

Comment: Там Оптимус ответил=)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('m-cat-ul').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if( !e.target.matches('li') ) return;
  
  let active = this.querySelector('.m-cat-li__active');
  // this ссылается на объект, в контексте которого вызвана функция.
  // здесь, это 'm-cat-ul'

  if( active ) active.classList.remove('m-cat-li__active');
  
  e.target.classList.add('m-cat-li__active');
});
```

```css
.m-cat ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.m-cat li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.m-cat li::before {
  content: "";
  height: 1.5px;
  background: #999;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: .2s ease;
}

.m-cat li:not(.m-cat-li__active):hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.m-cat-li__active {
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<aside class="m-cat">
  <nav>
    <ul id="m-cat-ul">
      <li data-url="/">Все товары</li>
      <li>Электроника</li>
      <li>Дом</li>
      <li>Автотовары</li>
      <li>Спорт и развлечения</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</aside>
```

P.s. а у стрелочных функций нет своего this) Поэтому не стоит везде их использовать. Они задуманы именно для коротеньких функций из одной-двух строчек.

Comment: Спасибо конечно, помогли в удаление свойства с предыдущего актива. Но я видимо не написал этого. После клика на элемент, у него появляется полоска,все правильно, но если навести на этот же элемент, то у него срабатывает еще раз hover. Как его отключить?

Comment: Про стрелочные функции верно подмечено!

Comment: @Евгений `.m-cat li:hover::before` → `.m-cat li:not(.m-cat-li__active):hover::before`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Ого.. Можете в двух словах объяснить это?) `.m-cat li:not(.m-cat-li__active):hover::before`

Comment: @Евгений, «Внутри элемента `.m-cat`, все теги `li` у которых `:нет(.m-cat-li__active)` такого класса... применить стили при `:hover` наведении, к псевдоэлементу `::before`» )

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Ооо, спасибо, давно я вебом не занимался)))